# Error when installing react-native-gesture-handler with npm

Tags: react-native, npm, react-navigation, npm-install

I am trying to run `npm install react-native-gesture-handler` but my terminal gives me this error:

```
SAMETs-MBP:HelloWorld developer$ npm install react-native-gesture-handler
npm ERR! path /Users/developer/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! code EISGIT
npm ERR! git /Users/developer/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.
npm ERR! git     /Users/developer/HelloWorld/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view
npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,
npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/developer/.npm/_logs/2019-05-14T05_27_08_555Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me on this? I searched online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: delete your node_module folder then use npm i

Comment: I did. I received same error trying to run ```npm i```

Comment: @SametMutevelli Delete your node_module and package-lock.json, Clear your npm cache, and then run npm install, Also what is the react-native version your using

Comment: @SametMutevelli I get the same error! Did you solve this issue? If yes, please share your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue today. Tried three steps and worked!

1. Removed the folder **'react-native-safe-area-view'** manually
2. Removed cache using `npm start -- --reset-cache`
3. Run the command `npm --save install react-native-gesture-handler`

Update: I also found out deleting git folder inside the `node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view` will fix this issue. Thanks @ThaJay

Hope it will help!

Comment: You ony need to delete the `.git` folder inside `react-native-safe-area-view`.

Answer (score 1):

**use yarn**. using **npm** gave me an error. I tried with **yarn**, it didn't give any issue.

Answer (score 1):

running **`rm -rf node_modules/*/.git/`**  from root folder fixed my issue. reference https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view/issues/73

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **.git** folder inside **your_project_dir/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view**. 
And it worked for me.